# pip install pyaudio error code 1

Tags: python, cmd.exe

hello so when I run.

```
pip install pyaudio --allow-external pyaudio --allow-unverified pyaudio
```

I get this back and would rly like some help rn.

```
Command "c:\users\ramyar.mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\RAMYAR~1.MOH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffcb_0zk\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\RAMYAR~1.MOH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4u_zbgs3\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\RAMYAR~1.MOH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffcb_0zk\pyaudio\
```

I really need python audio to be setup correctly on my pc so I can run this code I made and cant get it to install any suggestions are thanked for.

Comment: What did you do so far to solve the issue your self?

Comment: well I've done a lot of diggin around and cant find any fix and then I called my uncle that does a lot of computing he is a software dev and he told me to post my problems on this site and since he is on a OSX he wasnt able to help much

Comment: You may want to look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52283840/3395469).

Comment: I don't have any experience with your issue myself, so this is just feedback on your question: Your question doesn't really reflect any previous research or attempts to fix it, you should change that. It makes an answer more likely. Make sure to keep you're question structured and readable as it gets "bigger" while you add more information. Your question doesn't really reflect any previous research or attempts to fix it, you should change that. It makes an answer more likely. Make sure to keep you're question structured and readable as it gets "bigger" while you add more information.